# Get value of email using pluck - php laravel

Tags: php, laravel

```
$response['inserted_data'] =
array:3 [
    0 => array:16 [
        "name" => "Khv"
        "emails" => array:1 [
            0 => array:1 [
                "email" => "demo@yahoo.com"
            ]
        ]
    ]
    1 => array:18 [
        "name" => "Aesha"
        "emails" => array:1 [
            0 => array:1 [
                "email" => "test2@gmail.com"
            ]
        ]
    ]
```

How to get email values `demo@yahoo.com` and `test2@gmail.com` using `pluck - php laravel` and then from that emails need to get _id from database and update that records.

Comment: Unclear with your question please elaborate more, then we will help you...

Comment: 1) I want to get all email id using pluck  2) once i get all email ids then want to get _id from database using that emails with laravel query

Comment: How are you getting the array in your question? Is it something you've hardcoded, are you getting it from the `Request` or something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the below code :
Assuming your data look likes below array i.e $arrays.

```
$arrays=[ 
                    ["name" => "Khv","emails" => 
                        [0 => ["email" => "demo1@yahoo.com"]
                        ]
                    ],
                    ["name" => "asy", "emails" => 
                        [0 => ["email" => "demo2@yahoo.com"]
                        ]
                    ]
                ];
        $emails=collect();
        foreach ($arrays as $array) {
            $emails->push($array['emails'][0]['email']);
        }
        dd($emails);
```

Note : You can't use pluck on array, it can be only used on collection.

Comment: now how can i get _id from database using this emails

Comment: Just an FYI, you can pluck from an array using `array_pluck` which is a Laravel helper function, or you can use `array_column` which is a php function.

Comment: $getId = Repo::get('JobRequestRepository')->getDetailsByInput($emails);        
      if (isset($input['email'])) {
            $value = $value->where('emails.email', $input['email']);
        } can get all id from this query?

Comment: Can you please share the table where this emails are stored? assuming it's stored in users table.we can find it using $users = User::whereIN('email',$emails)->get();
        dd($users);

Answer (score 0):

You get the value from the pluck like below way.

```
User::all()->pluck('email');
```

Comment: collect(array_values($response['inserted_data']))->pluck('email')->all(); can i use this? it is returning null value

Comment: No you can use this query like ::  **Model::all()->pluck('field_name');**

Comment: its returning null  Collection {#930
  #items: array:3 [
    0 => null
    1 => null
    2 => null
  ]
}